# Invalid length error for beginner

Tags: r

I have checked previous questions but couldn't find an answer

```
 columnmean<-function(y){
    n<-ncol(y)
    means<-numeric(n)
    for(i in 1:n){
        means[i]<-mean(y[,i])
    }
    means}
```

I simply cannot understand the error, even the code seems right. Also, i get some dimension error if i input the value of n in this line

```
 means[i]<-mean(y[,i])
```

Comment: You want to get the mean for each column of a data is it right ? then why not using this apply(your data name,2,mean)  . however, if you want to use that loop, can you please also add a data so we can reproduce your error and see what is wrong ? I think third line should be as.numeric . Note that you should create a matrix before you run the loop , a matrix that has the same dimension as your data output

Comment: Why not use the built-in function `colMeans`? If you want help, you should also give a minimal reproducible code (with data, using `dput` for example)

Comment: @Learner: the third line is correct, it creates an empty numeric vector of length n that will be filled with the for loop. And if you run a mean over each column, you then get a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: @DeveauP you are right but then it should be outside of the loop , no? because each time it will create a new vector and no results will be saved

Comment: The `numeric` is outside the loop. What is inside the loop is the association of the i th element of the vector with value "mean of i th column". I think the issue comes from the input `y`

Comment: Your function seems to be OK. Applied to a numerical matrix it does not give any error and it provides the same output as `colMeans()`. Maybe you can just start a new R session and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reproduction of the error:

```
columnmean<-function(y){
  n <- ncol(y)
  means <- numeric(n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    means[i] <- mean(y[,i])
  }
  means
}
columnmean(1:10)
```

If `y` is a vector the result of `ncol(y)` is `NULL`. The following calculation in your function raises the error.
Also `colMeans(1:10)` will cause an error (another error because of better internal checking of the argument).

So, your code is correct for twodimensional data, e.g.:

```
columnmean(BOD)
# [1]  3.666667 14.833333
```

The error depends from `y` (`y` with only one dimension, i.e. a vector ~~> error).